# How to do migration of reports from Crystal Reports to Business Objects Enterprise

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I migrate reports from Crystal Reports to Business Objects Enterprise?

Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions or advice?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a migration as much as it is a deployment.

In Crystal Reports, select File | Save As..., click the Enterprise shortcut, select the desired folder and click Save.

You can also add reports to BOE via the InfoView and CMC applications.